# RegEx for movement G-Code +Python

Tags: python, regex

I've got following regular expression:

```
self.PosCheck = re.compile('[gG0-3]{1,3}|\s{1,2}[xX]-?([0-9.]{1,15})|\s[yY]-?([0-9.]{1,15})|\s[zZ]-?([0-9.]{1,15})')
```

it works very fine and detects every value of each axis and sort these values into different groups if they're available. For example: `position_response = "G0 X100 Y200 Z300"`

```
regline = self.PosCheck.findall(position_response)
    for i in regline: 
        if i[0]:
            print (i[0]) #prints 100
        if i[1]:
            print (i[1]) #prints 200
        if i[2]:
            print (i[2]) #prints 300
```

But independently if there is a gG0-3 or not. The RegEx should not deliver any answer in groups if there is no gG0-3. How can i fix that?

Comment: should it always start with `G...`?

Comment: yes, but with variable amount of mentioned axes, for example "G0 X100 Z20" or "G0 Y100"

Comment: would this `"g111 X100 Y200 Z300"` be a valid input?

Comment: the first section (your mentioned g111) should be a small "g" or big one "G", and a number between 0 and 3 (gG0-3), 111 would be to high.

Comment: Could you give couple example inputs, both valid & not valid and expected outputs?

Comment: No problem, here some valid ones: "G0 X200" "G1 Y300" "g0 X10 Y20 Z30" "g3 X10 Z20" and here some invalid ones: "h0 X100 H20" "G5 X100 Y200" "G3 A100 B200 C300"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with named groups and a single match

```
import re

PosCheck = re.compile(
'(?i)^[gG0-3]{1,3}(?:\s+x-?(?P<x>[0-9.]{1,15})|\s+y-?(?P<y>[0-9.]{1,15})|\s+z-?(?P<z>[0-9.]{1,15}))*$')

for position_response in [
    "G0 X100 Y200 Z300",
    "G0 x100 z20",
    "x150 y30",
    ]:
    i = PosCheck.match(position_response)
    if i:
        print(position_response, '->', i.groupdict())
    else:
        print(position_response, '->', None)
```

output:

```
G0 X100 Y200 Z300 -> {'x': '100', 'y': '200', 'z': '300'}
G0 x100 z20 -> {'x': '100', 'y': None, 'z': '20'}
x150 y30 -> None
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much Gribouillis!

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work for G1 codes.

Comment: @Rupin this is  an old post. What are G1 codes?